# SPsite in SharePoint 2013 can't call other Site Collection with URL

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, event-receiver

I am trying to access a different site collection through an Event receiver. Event receiver does what i want but it does in the same site collection. 
i have following code

```
 using (SPSite destsite = new SPSite("http://man:8787/ONE/"))
  {
    string currentURL = destsite.Url.ToString()  

   }
```

**i always get currentURL = http://man:8787**

i never get 
   **currentURL = http://man:8787/ONE**

I have a working site collection at **http://man:8787/ONE**

is there anything changed in 2013, am i doing anything wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that `http://man:8787/ONE/` is a separate site collection and not a separate site in the same site collection?

Comment: boom yeah they are sub sites in same site collections i never realized that...i am being stupid here.....i hate myself so much now....thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing we can assume one or two things:

`http://man:8787` is a SiteCollection - call it with `SPSite`

If current url from the `SPSite("http://man:8787/ONE/")` always is `http://man:8787` then `http://man:8787/ONE/` is a website inside that sitecollection, hence you should use `SPWeb`.

If you want that website at that specific location, use the following code:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://man:8787/ONE/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    { 
       //magic happens here
    }
}
```

Edit:
There is an awesome answer over at SharePoint.SE, which lifts some of the confusion around SPSite, SPWeb etc:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/getting-my-head-round-spsite-vs-spweb-vs-anything-else